# brands images in product page

Tags: php, product-attribute, html

i have an attribute named `manufacturer` which contains my products brands. Like: `Apple Co`
and my brands images are stored in: `media/wysiwyg/queldorei/shopper/brands`. With names like: `apple_co`
Now i want to show my brands images in the product pages. and i want theme to be clickable. and head me to a page with all of those brands products.

i will be thankful if you experts help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add bottom code in this file: `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'); $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer(); echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/result/?manufacturer='.$manufacturerId.'&q='.$manufacturerName.'">' ?> <img src="../media/wysiwyg/queldorei/shopper/brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$manufacturerName); ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('to see more from') ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->__('click here') ?>" /></a>
```

brand logo images are stored in : `/media/wysiwyg/queldorei/shopper/brands/`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to update template files to show the manufacturer(s) logo.

Open `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Add:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct();
 $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
 $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
 echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]='.$manufacturerId.'">' ?>
 <img src="../media/catalog/brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$manufacturerName); ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>" /></a>
```

Manufacturer images in this example are relative to /media/catalog/brands/

Comment: it gets the brand to the product page but when i click on it shows this error: `The requested URL /catalogsearch/advanced/result/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Excellent! Then your initial question is answered. Please accept this answer for posterity.

You're `/catalogsearch/advanced/result/` doesn't exist, so you're getting that error. Simply change the `href` in the link to point to a more suitable location (Your manufacturers page).